# Generate Report Programmatically

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Let's say that I have created a report using the Acumatica Report Designer and it is linked to the relevant DAC.

I also have a custom screen with an Action. When the user executes this action, I want to generate the report so that it the user downloads it as pdf.

What is the approach to generate the report as PDF programmatically through the Acumatica API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to code snippet below for an example showing how to generate report programmatically as PDF file and show SaveFileDialog to download/save generated PDF:

```
public PXAction<IOITInboundTestWorkOrder> GenerateReportAndRedirectToFile;
[PXButton]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Generate Report and Download as PDF")]
protected void generateReportAndSaveToDB()
{
    Actions.PressSave();
    PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, () =>
    {
        PX.SM.FileInfo file = null;
        using (Report report = PXReportTools.LoadReport("SO641012", null))
        {
            var orderNbr = ITWO.Current.OrderNbr;
            if (report == null) throw new Exception("Unable to access Acumatica report writter for specified report : " + "SO641012");
            Dictionary<string, string> prams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            prams["ITWONbr"] = orderNbr;
            PXReportTools.InitReportParameters(report, prams, PXSettingProvider.Instance.Default);
            ReportNode repNode = ReportProcessor.ProcessReport(report);
            IRenderFilter renderFilter = ReportProcessor.GetRenderer(ReportProcessor.FilterPdf);

            using (StreamManager streamMgr = new StreamManager())
            {
                renderFilter.Render(repNode, null, streamMgr);
                string fileName = string.Format("Inbound Test Work Order #{0}.pdf", orderNbr);
                file = new PX.SM.FileInfo(fileName, null, streamMgr.MainStream.GetBytes());
            }
        }
        if (file != null)
        {
            throw new PXRedirectToFileException(file, true);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to deal with exposing the URL, the accepted method appears to be to invoke a method to store the file to the Acumatica record and then retrieve the file via the API: [Get report output in PDF fromat via Acumatica REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319158/get-report-output-in-pdf-fromat-via-acumatica-rest-api?rq=1)

Comment: Please upvote the idea to make report generation functionality available through the API without saving a file to Acumatica! https://feedback.acumatica.com/ideas/ACU-I-1852

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with the accepted answer since I am using the REST API and for some reason the PXRedirectToFileException does work there (it doesn't return a location header). I came up with this really clunky solution that casues the file URL to be exposed in an exception.

```
using SiteStatus = PX.Objects.IN.Overrides.INDocumentRelease.SiteStatus;
using System.Linq;
using PX.Common;
using CRLocation = PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location;
using PX.Objects.AR.CCPaymentProcessing;
using PX.Objects.AR.CCPaymentProcessing.Common;
using PX.Objects.AR.CCPaymentProcessing.Helpers;
using PX.Objects.Common;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.SO;
using PX.Reports;
using PX.Reports.Data;
using PX.Data.Reports;
using PX.SM;

namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
  
  public class SOInvoiceEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<SOInvoiceEntry>
  {

    #region Event Handlers
    protected virtual void ARInvoice_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e){
        CreateInvoicePDF.SetEnabled(true);
    }

     public PXAction<ARInvoice> CreateInvoicePDF;
     [PXButton]
     [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create Invoice PDF", Enabled = true, Visible = false)]
     public virtual void createInvoicePDF()
     {
            //Report Paramenters
            Dictionary<String, String> parameters = new Dictionary<String, String>();
            parameters["DocType"] = Base.Document.Current.DocType;
            parameters["RefNbr"] = Base.Document.Current.RefNbr;

            //Report Processing
            PX.Reports.Controls.Report _report = PXReportTools.LoadReport("SO643000",null);
            PXReportTools.InitReportParameters(_report, parameters, SettingsProvider.Instance.Default);
            ReportNode reportNode = ReportProcessor.ProcessReport(_report);

            // Generate PDF
            byte[] data = PX.Reports.Mail.Message.GenerateReport(reportNode, ReportProcessor.FilterPdf).First();
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Guid.NewGuid(), "Invoice" + Base.Document.Current.RefNbr + ".pdf", null, data);

            // Store data in session
            PXContext.SessionTyped<PXSessionStatePXData>().FileInfo[file.UID.ToString()] = file;

            // Include file URL in exception. The client will parse the filname and fetch the URL in a subsequent request.
            PXRedirectToFileException e =  new PXRedirectToFileException(file.UID, 0, true, true);

            string url = e.Url;

            throw new FileUrlException(url);
     }

    #endregion

    }

    class FileUrlException : PXException {
        public FileUrlException(string message) : base(message) {

        }
    }

}
```

The downside is that this action can only be used via the API.
I added the action to the web services endpoint. On the other end I used regex to extract the string out of the exception message and performed a get request to fetch the file.